# Checkbox onclick filter results from db

Tags: php

Website is built in wordpress. My goal is to filter results from database when user clicks on checkbox.

Currently I'm doing that with GET method. I think that I have complicated it too much. On page load all check box are checked, and when users uncheck checkbox, a post with that taxonomy is filtered out. My code is currently working and here it is:

Setting checkbox checked:

```
$actual_link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";      
if ( $actual_link == 'https://www.example.com/') {
    $var_check = 1;
}
```

Checkboxes:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" method="GET" id="filter">      
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='f'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="f" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($face =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite facebook" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Facebook</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='t'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($twitter=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite twitter2" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Twitter</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='te'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="te" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($telegram=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite telegram2" style="margin-left:5px;"><span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Telegram</span></div><br>   
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='r'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="r" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($reddit=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite reddit" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Reddit</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='e'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="e" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($email=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="sprite email" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Flter by Email</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='ph'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ph" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($phone=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite phone" style="margin-left:2px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Phone</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='b'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($bitcointalk=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite bitcointalk" style="margin-left:3px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by BitcoinTalk</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='k'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="k" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($kyc=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="sprite kyc" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by KYC</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='y'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="y" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($youtube=='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>> <div class="sprite youtube" style="margin-left:2px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Filter by YouTube</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='l'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="l" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($linkedin=='1') || ($var_check == 1) )  {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="sprite linkedin" style="margin-left:5px;"> <span class="tooltiptext">Flter by LinkedIn</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='eth'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="eth" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($ethereum =='1')  || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="ethereum" style="margin-left:5px;">ETH<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Ethereum</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='neo'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="neo" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($neo =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="neo" style="margin-left:5px;">NEO<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by NEO</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='xml'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xml" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($stellar =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="stellar" style="margin-left:5px;">XML<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Stellar</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='waves'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="waves" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($waves =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="waves" style="margin-left:5px;">WAVES<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Waves</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='kmd'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="kmd" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($komodo =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="komodo" style="margin-left:5px;">KMD<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Komodo</span></div><br>
    <input type='hidden' value='0' name='own'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="own" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php if ( ($own =='1') || ($var_check == 1) ) {echo 'checked';}?>><div class="own" style="margin-left:5px;">OWN<span class="tooltiptext">Filter by Own chain</span></div><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="req">
</form>
```

Here is getting of the variables:

```
if ( isset($_GET['f']) && $_GET['f'] == '1') {$face='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['f']) ) {$face = '0'; }  else {$face='facebook';}
if ( isset($_GET['t']) && $_GET['t'] == '1' ) {$twitter='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['t']) ) {$twitter = '0'; } else {$twitter='twitter';}
if ( isset($_GET['te']) && $_GET['te'] == '1' ) {$telegram='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['te']) ) {$telegram = '0'; } else {$telegram='telegram';}
if ( isset($_GET['r']) && $_GET['r'] == '1' ) {$reddit='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['r']) ) {$reddit = '0'; } else {$reddit='reddit';}
if ( isset($_GET['e']) && $_GET['e'] == '1' ) {$email='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['e']) ) {$email = '0'; } else {$email='email';}
if ( isset($_GET['ph']) && $_GET['ph'] == '1' ) {$phone='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['ph']) ) {$phone = '0'; } else {$phone='phone';}
if ( isset($_GET['b']) && $_GET['b'] == '1' ) {$bitcointalk='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['b']) ) {$bitcointalk = '0'; } else {$bitcointalk='bitcointalk';}
if ( isset($_GET['k']) && $_GET['k'] == '1' ) {$kyc='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['k']) ) {$kyc = '0'; } else {$kyc='kyc';}
if ( isset($_GET['y']) && $_GET['y'] == '1' ) {$youtube='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['y']) ) {$youtube = '0'; } else {$youtube='youtube';}
if ( isset($_GET['l']) && $_GET['l'] == '1' ) {$linkedin='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['l']) ) {$linkedin = '0'; } else {$linkedin='linkedin';}           
if ( isset($_GET['eth']) && $_GET['eth'] == '1' ) {$ethereum='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['eth']) ) {$ethereum = '0'; } else {$ethereum='ethereum';}
if ( isset($_GET['neo']) && $_GET['neo'] == '1' ) {$neo='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['neo']) ) {$neo = '0'; } else {$neo='neo';}
if ( isset($_GET['xml']) && $_GET['xml'] == '1' ) {$stellar='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['xml']) ) {$stellar = '0'; } else {$stellar='stellar';}
if ( isset($_GET['waves']) && $_GET['waves'] == '1' ) {$waves='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['waves']) ) {$waves = '0'; }  else {$waves='waves';}
if ( isset($_GET['kmd']) && $_GET['kmd'] == '1' ) {$komodo='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['kmd']) ) {$komodo = '0'; } else {$komodo='komodo';}
if ( isset($_GET['own']) && $_GET['own'] == '1' ) {$own='1';} elseif ( !isset($_GET['own']) ) {$own = '0'; } else {$own='own';}
```

And finally the query:

```
$tax_query_args[] = array(                  
 'relation' => 'AND',                   
 array(
    'taxonomy' => 'filters',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => array ($face, $twitter, $telegram, $reddit, $email, $phone, $bitcointalk, $kyc, $youtube, $linkedin),
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
     ),                         
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'platform',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => array ($ethereum, $neo, $stellar, $waves, $komodo, $own),
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
     ),                     
);
```

This is currently working and I'm getting the desired result. But how to do with POST method on the same page, so that URL is not changed with parameters. I suppose I will have to use AJAX, but I'm not experienced with it.

I will appreciate any help or guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that with checkboxes, if a checkbox isn't checked then nothing will be sent to the server for that form value